# Check if more than two options with specific class are selected

Tags: jquery

http://fiddle.jshell.net/oc48qztr/

I have four selects with model of cars and one airplane. 
I don't know how to check if more than two options with specific class are selected.

After choosing more than two cars it should show an alert.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if (($('select[name*="select-model"] option:selected').is('.car').length > 2)) {
    alert("You can't choose more than two cars!");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select-model">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option class="boe airplane" value="0">Boeing - This is not a car!</option>
  <option class="vol car" value="0">Volkswagen</option>
  <option class="kia car" value="0">KIA</option>
  <option class="bwm car" value="0">BMW</option>
  <option class="mer car" value="0">Mercedes</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="select-model">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option class="boe airplane" value="0">Boeing - This is not a car!</option>
  <option class="vol car" value="0">Volkswagen</option>
  <option class="kia car" value="0">KIA</option>
  <option class="bwm car" value="0">BMW</option>
  <option class="mer car" value="0">Mercedes</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="select-model">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option class="boe airplane" value="0">Boeing - This is not a car!</option>
  <option class="vol car" value="0">Volkswagen</option>
  <option class="kia car" value="0">KIA</option>
  <option class="bwm car" value="0">BMW</option>
  <option class="mer car" value="0">Mercedes</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="select-model">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option class="boe airplane" value="0">Boeing - This is not a car!</option>
  <option class="vol car" value="0">Volkswagen</option>
  <option class="kia car" value="0">KIA</option>
  <option class="bwm car" value="0">BMW</option>
  <option class="mer car" value="0">Mercedes</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit">Click</button>
```

Comment: whether you will be able to change the html markup

Comment: also whether you have a fixed number of types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need-

**Demo**- http://fiddle.jshell.net/oc48qztr/5/

```
$('button').click(function() {

    if (($('select option:selected[class*="car"]').length > 2)) {

        alert("You can't choose more than two cars!");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var carCount = $('option.car:selected').length;
    var planeCount = $('option.airplane:selected').length;
    console.log("car", carCount, "else", planeCount)
});
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/oc48qztr/1/

Based on the values, you can implement your logic.